# TokenGuard class always need api_token

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am using AngularJs and Laravel 5.4

In the default guard, I changed the `web guard` to `api`. Finally it looks like below.

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

when i send the request using username and password from Angular Js....I always get invalid credentials because..

`TokenGuard` class has a method called `validate` which expects api_token value but I am on the login page.

I am assuming that in order to get the token, I need `$this->guard(web)` in login method?

Is it correct approach or Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

By default all routes defined in `routes/api.php` have the `api` middleware as defined in `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider::mapApiRoutes()`. Therefore, you always need to pass api_token.

What you can do is, in your api routes, define the login route like this

```
Route::post('login', 'api\AuthController@login'); //out of the group
```

And post from AngularJS

```
$http.post({
    url: 'http://localhost/api/login',
    data: $scope.userda,
    headers: {
        Authorization: ''
    }
}).then(...)
```

Then define all your other routes in a group with `auth:api`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    //Other routes here
});
```

In angular, set the Authorization headers with the value of `api_token`. So before login, it will be empty and after login it will have the value of the user api_token.

Comment: You are missing closing single quote in your quote here `auth:api` and second is how can login route be wrapped in auth:api middleware? Token is not present at this moment. I need token using user name and password in my login page. Only then I will be able to make further calls using token. Please let me know if you need more info about my question.

Comment: My login route is out of the Group.

Comment: How can i do login using `TokenGuard`? TokenGuard class has a Validate method which need token... But my login request is yet to fetch token. I meant, what will u write in login method in the controller to get the username and password validated from tokenguard?

Comment: Oh now I get what you mean. Define your login route in `routes/web.php`. You will have access to normal Auth. Then just return Json() from there with all user details. and all the routes, they go through `api` for TokenGuard authentication.

Comment: why web guard? Why not api guard? Can't I do the login using api guard?

Comment: Api guard works with `api_token` only. And as you said. You don't have before login, therefore api guad cannot authenticate you.

Comment: Should I mix SessionGuard and TokenGuard? Is it safe to use Laravel TokenGuard or I should go for JWT?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend mixing as I never tried such thing and know nothing about the side effects. I use the same setup as you. Only difference is that I login from normal form (PHP) and redirect to angular with `api_token` already set.

Comment: You are mixing things too. I thing u are using tokenguard and session guard both

Comment: Nope. My login form is purely PHP in `/login`. My angular app sits in `/app`. The route `app` is protected by auth `Web guard` but everything that goes through `api` is using `api guard`. I know what you mean, but in my controllers `Auth::check()` won't work because request come in JSON. But if by mixing you mean I use both guard, yes I do, but at different levels. I just think it's more easier for me like that.